# detecting browser back button in javascript/jquery without using any external plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, back-button

I want to detect browser back button in java-script/jquery without using any external plugins.

I am going to support following browsers

**IE8,IE9,FireFox,Chrome**

I googled so many links and found below part of code from code project

```
<body onbeforeunload=”HandleBackFunctionality()”>

function HandleBackFunctionality()
{
    if(window.event)
   {
        if(window.event.clientX < 40 && window.event.clientY < 0)
        {
            alert("Browser back button is clicked...");
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Browser refresh button is clicked...");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(event.currentTarget.performance.navigation.type == 1)
        {
             alert("Browser refresh button is clicked...");
        }
        if(event.currentTarget.performance.navigation.type == 2)
        {
             alert("Browser back button is clicked...");
        }
    }
}
```

The above code working fine IE browser. that means i can able to get the window.event.clientX and clientY values in IE browser. but in chrome/firefox not working.

When browser back button is clicked, i need to refresh the page.

how can i detect browser back button click event in all browsers (IE,firefox,chrome)

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are looking for `window.onpopstate` function. [Mozilla API documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WindowEventHandlers.onpopstate) [Caniuse.Popstate](http://caniuse.com/#feat=history)

Comment: @Mystreyos but popstate event is like HTML5 event right ? but i want to support IE8 too. could you please update more details regarding this.Thanks

Comment: Looking for **exactly** the same thing, how to detect back and forward button click in IE8.

Comment: @lowtechsun i tried with out external scripts but it is creating some issues.so i have implemented with custom scripts only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That can be simply dropped into your web page, and when the user clicks back, it will call a function. The default function on this call is a javascript alert “Back Button Clicked”.

To replace this functionality, you simply need to override the OnBack function. This can be done by using the code below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
bajb_backdetect.OnBack = function()
{
   alert('You clicked it!');
}
</script>
```

This will now replace the “Back Button Clicked” alert with a “You clicked it!’” alert.
**support following browsers
IE8,IE9,FireFox,Chrome**
[**Browser Back Button Detection**](http://www.bajb.net/2010/02/browser-back-button-detection/)
Or using `jquery`
[**Catching browser back**](http://www.typo3-media.com/blog/catching-browser-back.html)
Using standard `javascript`
[**Mastering The Back Button With Javascript**](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_The_Back_Button_With_Javascript)

Comment: Thanks.whether it requires to refer any external scripts ?

Comment: When you use a large library like jQuery.
3 KB is not a reasonable limit for a script.

Comment: it requires "backfix.min.js". so i need without any external plugins clearly mentioned in this question

Comment: yes.i understood your point but for some other reasons we are not preferring external plugins for this

Comment: The last link is no external script:``Mastering The Back Button With Javascript``

Comment: am using this but when click back button i need to refresh the previous page URL instead of getting from cache. how can  i?

Comment: ``OnBack`` event set value in cookie like ``$.cookie("test", 1, { expires : 10 });`` and in ``beforload`` event at previous page URL read cookie and do your work.

Comment: Both "Catching browser back" and "Mastering The Back Button With Javascript" are gone or cannot be reached. What was the the pure JS code for back button detection in IE, if possible down to IE8? Also don't want to include the lib as that also changes URL hash but I am doing that myself, so really just need reliable back button on IE detection. Thank you.

Comment: the only problem i see is that the console blinks terribly when I'm in debug. So, when I debug, I need to comment out the line <script src="~/Scripts/backfix.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 1):

Since you are supporting IE 8 and 9 as well, there isnt a single method that will help you solve this. You could use the history API of html5 but that doesn't support IE8 and 9. As mysteryos mentioned in the above comment, you could use window.onPopState for chrome, firefox etc, and for IE you could create a separate js file and use conditional statements to fire it when the user uses IE.

For example:

```
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
    <script src="youIESpecificfile.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Read more about the HTML5 History API here: [onPopState by mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WindowEventHandlers.onpopstate)

Hope this helps!